# Dynamo JS SDK v3: how do I use an array in ExpressionAttributeValues (with Typescript)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

```
import { [various] } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';  


// see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/index.html
const dynamoClient = new DynamoDB({ region: parameters.AWS_REGION });
const dynamoDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(dynamoClient);  

...

const params: UpdateItemCommandInput = {
    TableName: dynamoCollections.divisionVariety,
    Key: { divisionID: { N: `${divisionID}` } },
    UpdateExpression:
        'SET accounts = LIST_APPEND(IF_NOT_EXISTS(accounts, []), :accountsAndBrands)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':accountsAndBrands': accounts,  // <=========== HERE
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
};

try {
    const data = await dynamoDocClient.send(
        new UpdateItemCommand(params)
    );
    ...
```

I need to upsert into the `accounts` property of an existing doc. The `accounts` arg is an array of POJOs.

The problem is that I'm getting `TS2322: Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'AttributeValue'.` on `':accountsAndBrands': accounts`. According to the docs I should be getting marshaling of `accounts`. I tried adding an `as` but didn't think it would work and it doesn't: `TS2352: Conversion of type 'unknown[]' to type 'AttributeValue' may be a mistake`. If I add an `as unknown` I get a marshalling error in `serializeAws_json1_0AttributeValue`. If I just `ts-ignore` the problem line I also get a marshaling error.

If I replace the `accounts` object with a plain string I still get `TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AttributeValue'.`

How do I get Typescript and the DocumentClient marshaling to coexist here? It really seems like the type definitions don't allow for an array where it's expecting an `AttributeValue` interface.

The docs say I should get proper marshalling for free:

> The document client affords developers the use of native JavaScript types instead of AttributeValues to simplify the JavaScript development experience with Amazon DynamoDB. JavaScript objects passed in as parameters are marshalled into AttributeValue shapes required by Amazon DynamoDB. Responses from DynamoDB are unmarshalled into plain JavaScript objects by the DocumentClient. The DocumentClient does not accept AttributeValues in favor of native JavaScript types.

docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/index.html

update: I actually got an insert to work, but I had to use an object that conformed to `AttributeValue`: `L: [{ S: 'Cookies' }, { S: 'Coffee' }, { N: '3.14159' }]`. But when I checked Dynamo the values were not unmarshaled, there were stored as `[{ S: 'Cookies' }, { S: 'Coffee' }, { N: '3.14159' }]` instead of `['Cookies', 'Coffee', 3.14159]`. This looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are mixing up the update command and input types from `@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb` and `@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb`.

If you dont't want to use the Attribute value, you should use `UpdateCommand` and `UpdateCommandInput` from `@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb`. It should work like this:

```
import { [various] } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { DynamoDBDocumentClient, UpdateCommand, UpdateCommandInput } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';  

const dynamoClient = new DynamoDB({ region: parameters.AWS_REGION });
const dynamoDocClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(dynamoClient);  

...
const params: UpdateCommandInput = {   // from @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb
    TableName: dynamoCollections.divisionVariety,
    Key: { divisionID: { N: `${divisionID}` } },
    UpdateExpression:
        'SET accounts = LIST_APPEND(IF_NOT_EXISTS(accounts, []), :accountsAndBrands)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':accountsAndBrands': accounts,  // <=========== THIS SHOULD BE ACCEPTED NOW
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
};

try {
    const data = await dynamoDocClient.send(
        new UpdateCommand(params)   // from @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb
    );
    ...
```